# Calculating upper and lower limits for a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, summation

I am asked to calculate the lower limit and upper limit (L5 and U5) for the linear function $y=13-3x$, between $x=0$ and $x=4$.

I have found that $Δx=4/5$, and that $x_0 =0$. However, I am getting my answers wrong when calculating $x1, x2, \dots x5$.

For example, I tried to calculate $x_1$ by doing $n/2 = 1/2$, however, this is incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You mean a Riemann sum?

Comment: I am not sure... The question did not address the Riemann sum, although it was a topic that our class touched on.